# ¿Como puedo solucionar este problema para que pueda usar Python 3 en Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, ide

Estuve usando un editor online de python pero queria usar sublime text 3 para ello. Estuve investigando pero no logro poder hacerlo. Instale el SublimeREPL y tambien agrege el siguiendo build system. Luego ya "deberia estar funcionando" al apretar crtl + b:

```
    {"target":"run_existing_window_command",
    "id":"repl_python_run",
    "file":"config/python/Main.sublime-menu"}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso me dice..

si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria.

Tambien probe construyendo mi propio build system(sacado de yt).

```
      {
        "shell_cmd": "start cmd /C \"(E:\usuarios\alumno\Archivos del programa\Python\python.exe \"$file\" || 
       set /p = Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...) && set /p = Successful execution. Press Enter to 
        exit...\"",
        "selector": "source.ypthon",
        "working_dir": "$file_dir"
     }
```

no me funciono, me salta no build sytem.

Ahi creo haberlo arreglado gracias a un comentario, no guarde el fichero.. xD
Ahora me funciona

Aunque tengo un error de Anaconda.. No se que signifique..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo que parece en la imagen, no has guardado el fichero antes de ejecutarlo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias ahora si me funciono guardando el fichero!! :)

Comment: Para este nuevo error, comprueba que el firewall de windows no te esté bloqueando el acceso a anaconda. Ejecuta el comando que te sugiere el mensaje de error para comprobarlo.